Using unsupported 32-bit MikTeX
32-bit MiKTex is now unsupported. But it still works. I am using TexStudio and it takes a long time to generate the error message ": major issue: You are running the unsupported 32-bit version of MiKTeX for Windows." But it then compiles the file.
Is there some way to continue with 32-bit MikTex and avoid the long time to produce the error message ?

why don't you install a newer miktex?

@UlrikeFischer I have a 32-bit operating system and a x64-based processor, will it work ?

I doubt it. You will need a 64bit OS.

you might do better with texlive rather than miktex, but can you not update the operating system?

@DavidCarlisle Yeah, that would work, I dont know how to do it. Its a scary option for me.

which would work, installing texlive or upgrading to 64 bit windows?  Is your operating system still supported by microsoft anyway? if it is out of support you should probably update anyway for security reasons irrespective of using tex

@DavidCarlisle I think texlive requires 64 bit but I will look into it again. And my OS is not supported, but I will continue to use it as long as possible, as I like it.

you may like it, but I wouldn't connect such a machine to the internet. you can get older texlives for https://texlive.info/historic/systems/w32tex/

@DavidCarlisle Yes, thank you for that link. I am afraid I will just have the same problem with a different distribution.

texlive won't give you complaints about being outdated each time you compile. it won't even know. only if you try to update the distribution it will tell you it is out of date. no idea what miktex does, but texlive doesn't phone home. of course, what it may do after somebody else has replaced bits of your os with malware is anybody's guess, but it isn't texlive's job to tell you what not to do.

You may like your OS but if you continue to use it, you are on your own. An older texlive may work, but if something breaks that works in a current system your chances to find someone with a similar setup who has the will and skills to help you are rather slim.
